# Spring Boot 2.0.3 JDBC session persistance error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a working Spring Boot Web application. We want to persist the session to the DB so I followed the spring tutorial, found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-jdbc.html)  and I am getting this error at startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.JdbcSessionConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'connectionsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'emFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Here is my connectionsConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectionsConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {


@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

@Bean
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean fact = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    fact.setAnnotatedPackages("com.xxx.persistence.model");
    fact.setPackagesToScan("com.xxx.persistence.model");
    fact.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return fact;
}
}
```

How do I get this to work?  Do I need to explicitly define the sessionFactory? I was under the impression that spring would handle this behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you provide then name of the bean like `@Bean(name="sessionFactory")` or `@Bean("sessionFactory")`?

Comment: I do not have that bean explicitly defined with a name.  I just have the sessionFactory() defined in the code.

Comment: Remove the whole `ConnectionsConfiguration` class. You don't need it. If you want Spring Session with JDBC spring boot also configures that automatically for you. YOU are reading the plain Spring Session docs, but you need to read the Spring Session with Spring Boot documentation instead.